# Yarn compile react project breaking upon updating react-scripts to 5.0.1

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

My project needed updating according to security scanners. I made one update, react-scripts to 5.0.1 which has resulted in a multitude of horrific errors. Specifically the one I can't shake is the following

```
Make sure that all the Babel plugins and presets you are using
are defined as dependencies or devDependencies in your package.json
file. It's possible that the missing plugin is loaded by a preset
you are using that forgot to add the plugin to its dependencies: you
can workaround this problem by explicitly adding the missing package
to your top-level package.json
src\theme\typography.js
  Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env'
```

I have tried:

- deleting node_modules and rerunning yarn install SEVERAL times
- removing presents and adding them back in again
- changing the browserlist
- adding to dev dependencies

None of these have worked. Is there anything else I can do?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@minimal/material-kit-react",
  "author": "minimals.cc",
  "licence": "MIT",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.18.6",
    "@craco/craco": "7.1.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@iconify/icons-ant-design": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-eva": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-ic": "^1.1.10",
    "@iconify/react": "^3.0.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.2.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.47",
    "@mui/material": "^5.1.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.1.1",
    "@mui/utils": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.5.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-tools": "6.2.1",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.21",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "5.2.3",
    "apexcharts": "^3.32.0",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1354.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "date-and-time": "^2.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "html-to-image": "^1.9.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.7.0",
    "node-html-to-image": "^3.2.4",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qrcode.react": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.1.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.6.4",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.9",
    "react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.6",
    "recharts": "^2.1.6",
    "shell-quote": "1.8.1",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.5",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

When I revert to @craco/craco@6.4.3 and react-scripts@4.0.1, I get

```
One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message
go away.
```

Even though I have "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11" in my dependencies. This seems like an incredibly idiotic error